# angluarjs delete original object after full copy to a new object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, object, deep-copy

I have a large JSON that I load into my app via a `<script>` tag.  the JS file that contains the JSON is about 280k. It is a standard JS definition:

```
var _countries = {"country:{"USA":{...},"GBR":{ ...},"FRA":( ...}, etc, etc ...}}} ;
```

It is loading into memory as the app launches and then I want to copy it to a new `$rootScope` variable, not just a reference to the original object, and then after its fully copied I want to delete the original `_countries` object.

```
$rootScope._countries= angular.copy(_countries) ;
_countries = null ;
```

But how can I tell when the object is fully copied before fully deleting the original `_countries` object? JS being asynchronous, I don't want to risk `$rootScope._countries` not having the full object before the null wipes out the original.

Also, is there a better way to copy the original object than using `angular.copy()` ?

Comment: Frame challenge:  Why do you want to do this instead of just assigning the reference?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat - I had a whole "duh" response, but then remembered why I went down this road in the first place.  Does angularJS not have its own memory for $scope variables?  Thus angularJS has one copy of the 280k object and standard JS has one too - thus two 280k objects sitting in memory...and I only need the angularJS one.

Comment: You’re overthinking this

Comment: Using `angular.copy()` will create a deep copy which will use more memory.   Just assigning the reference should use very little memory, you should just have two pointers to the same data.  The main reason to use `angular.copy()` is so that you can change details in one object but not the other.  Since you are removing your reference to the source object and it can be garbage collected, I don't think there is a point.  It will just take extra time and memory for a while to create the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR;

- If this is really just a simple json assignment, you don't need to worry about waiting.
- You also don't need to worry about deleting variables in JS to save memory.

#### Async

A simple data variable assignment like this will always be executed synchronously:

```
const foo = {...superBig} // definitely already just JSON
```

If you were reading from the JSON *in* the variable assignment, eg...

```
var _countries = funcToLoadJSON('path-to-my-json')
```

...that might be a different story depending on the implementation details since there are some methods that do that read synchronously and some that do it async. See [examples](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/).

#### Saving memory

You can't really delete any object in Javascript. JS engines try to figure out the “best” time to do garbage collection based on a handful of factors behind the scenes.